# Not getting DiscountPriceInfo in eBay API using python

Tags: python-2.7, api, ebay-api

I have been trying to get all the details of a product using the **Shopping API** in **python**.

```
from ebaysdk.shopping import Connection as Shopping
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as Finding

api = Finding(appid='My AppID',compatibility='987', config_file=None)
response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': 'My search'})

shop_api = Shopping(appid="MyAppID", config_file=None)
for item_count in range(int(response.reply.searchResult._count)):
    item = response.reply.searchResult.item[item_count]
    shop_response = shop_api.execute('GetSingleItem', {'ItemID': item.itemID ,'IncludeSelector':   'TextDescription, ItemSpecifics, Details'})
```

But in my response I'm **not getting** the **DiscountPriceInfoType** and **productID**.

Example response for the item id 331716839944 (using Shopping API) is shown below.

```
{
'Ack': 'Success',
'Timestamp': '2016-01-19T10:33:32.895Z',
'Version': '949',
'Build': 'E850_CORE_APILW_56481526_R1',
'Item': {
    'SKU': 'FITBITFB405BKL',
    'ShipToLocations': ['US', 'CA', 'GB', 'DK', 'RO', 'SK', 'BG', 'CZ', 'FI', 'HU', 'LV', 'LT', 'MT', 'EE', 'GR', 'PT', 'CY', 'SI', 'JP', 'CN', 'SE', 'KR', 'ID', 'TW', 'ZA', 'TH', 'BE', 'FR', 'HK', 'IE', 'NL', 'PL', 'ES', 'IT', 'DE', 'AT', 'RU', 'IL', 'MX', 'NZ', 'PH', 'SG', 'CH', 'NO', 'SA', 'UA', 'AE', 'QA', 'KW', 'BH', 'HR', 'MY', 'TR', 'BR', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'DO', 'PA', 'TT', 'GT', 'SV', 'HN', 'JM'],
    'Title': 'Fitbit Charge HR Wireless Activity Wristband, Black, Large',
    'PrimaryCategoryID': '44076',
    'IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled': 'false',
    'Seller': {
        'FeedbackRatingStar': 'RedShooting',
        'UserID': 'buydig',
        'FeedbackScore': '366130',
        'PositiveFeedbackPercent': '98.9'
    },
    'ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch': 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/Fitbit-Charge-HR-Wireless-Activity-Wristband-Black-Large-/331716839944',
    'BestOfferEnabled': 'false',
    'Location': 'Edison, NJ',
    'ReturnPolicy': {
        'Refund': 'Money Back',
        'ReturnsWithin': '30 Days',
        'Description': 'See item listing for details.',
        'ShippingCostPaidBy': 'Buyer',
        'ReturnsAccepted': 'Returns Accepted'
    },
    'HandlingTime': '1',
    'EndTime': '2016-01-23T22:22:59.000Z',
    'ItemID': '331716839944',
    'ListingStatus': 'Active',
    'Description': u 'Description here...',
    'QuantitySold': '2181',
    'CurrentPrice': {
        '_currencyID': 'USD',
        'value': '149.99'
    },
    'GalleryURL': 'http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/3317168399448080_8.jpg',
    'NewBestOffer': 'false',
    'PictureURL': ['http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFg5MzM=/z/oLcAAOSwJkJWkVjh/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F', 'http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/r3gAAOSwa-dWnSRZ/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F', 'http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EL0AAOSwFqJWnSRa/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F', 'http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/fzMAAOSwpRRWnSRZ/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F', 'http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/kM8AAOSwCypWnSRa/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F', 'http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/r5oAAOSwa-dWnSRa/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F'],
    'PrimaryCategoryName': 'Sporting Goods:Fitness, Running & Yoga:Fitness Technology:Other Fitness Technology',
    'Quantity': '2181',
    'ListingType': 'FixedPriceItem',
    'StartTime': '2015-11-24T22:22:59.000Z',
    'Country': 'US',
    'ConditionID': '1000',
    'PaymentMethods': ['PayPal'],
    'PrimaryCategoryIDPath': '888:15273:44075:44076',
    'AutoPay': 'true',
    'Storefront': {
        'StoreURL': 'http://stores.ebay.com/id=705087018',
        'StoreName': 'BuyDig'
    },
    'BidCount': '0',
    'QuantitySoldByPickupInStore': '0',
    'TimeLeft': 'P4DT11H49M27S',
    'ConvertedCurrentPrice': {
        '_currencyID': 'USD',
        'value': '149.99'
    },
    'ExcludeShipToLocation': ['FJ', 'NC', 'WS', 'PW', 'MH', 'KI', 'PF', 'WF', 'PG', 'AU', 'FM', 'VU', 'AS', 'NR', 'NU', 'CK', 'TO', 'SB', 'TV', 'GU', 'PM', 'BM', 'GL', 'BY', 'LU', 'BA', 'SJ', 'AL', 'JE', 'ME', 'LI', 'RS', 'MC', 'VA', 'MD', 'IS', 'MK', 'SM', 'AD', 'GG', 'GI', 'ZW', 'SC', 'SO', 'MU', 'GH', 'NG', 'CF', 'CI', 'CD', 'ER', 'BF', 'ZM', 'MR', 'NE', 'KM', 'DJ', 'GQ', 'SH', 'TG', 'MW', 'TN', 'CV', 'CG', 'GM', 'LY', 'RW', 'MG', 'SN', 'UG', 'GW', 'NA', 'CM', 'EG', 'GA', 'SZ', 'EH', 'LR', 'TZ', 'RE', 'AO', 'BJ', 'GN', 'MZ', 'ET', 'LS', 'ML', 'SL', 'YT', 'MA', 'BW', 'TD', 'DZ', 'KE', 'BI', 'GF', 'PE', 'EC', 'VE', 'UY', 'AR', 'FK', 'GY', 'PY', 'BO', 'SR', 'BN', 'KH', 'VN', 'LA', 'MO', 'KG', 'MV', 'LK', 'TM', 'UZ', 'KZ', 'MN', 'AF', 'NP', 'AZ', 'GE', 'TJ', 'BD', 'BT', 'IN', 'AM', 'PK', 'LB', 'IQ', 'JO', 'YE', 'OM', 'VI', 'AG', 'AI', 'VG', 'MS', 'BS', 'PR', 'DM', 'BZ', 'BB', 'KN', 'HT', 'AW', 'KY', 'LC', 'MQ', 'TC', 'GP', 'GD', 'AN', 'NI', 'VC'],
    'Site': 'US',
    'HitCount': '88088',
    'ConditionDisplayName': 'New',
    'ItemSpecifics': {
        'NameValueList': [{
            'Name': 'Brand',
            'Value': 'Fitbit'
        }, {
            'Name': 'MPN',
            'Value': 'FB405BKL'
        }]
    },
    'GlobalShipping': 'true'
}
```

}

I'm getting all the other fields except the DiscountPriceInfo.

Please provide a solution for this issue.

Comment: What is the item id thay are you trying to get DiscountPriceInfo for? You will only get DiscountPriceInfo back if the item has STP enabled and set by the seller of the item.

Comment: I got the item id from the Finding API (ebay). To get more details regarding the product i'm using the Shopping API (ebay).
I have also tried using the latest version API but not getting the DiscountPriceInfo field.

Comment: Try using your code with this item id: 331716839944

Comment: Still not getting the discount details. I have updated the code above. Hope it will you to provide a solution for this query.

Comment: Can you post the xml request and the response to item 331716839944 , I suspect that the Include Selectors are not being passed to eBay somehow.

Comment: I'am using the ebay sdk here.
Link to ebay sdk: https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python
Response for the item 331716839944 is posted above.

Comment: Ha, I was cracking my head on this, but it seems like the seller of that item raised the price so discount info was not longer applicable (no discount)

Try one of my items, I verified that there is discount price info using an XML Post request with the same selectors: 181440902172

Comment: yes,i'm getting DiscountPriceInfo for th item id 18440902172 but when I use the item id 141195688488 i'm getting 'DiscountPriceInfo': {'PricingTreatment': 'STP'} only. I'm not getting the price values.
url for item id 141195688488:http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hanes-Ultimate-Cotton-reg-Fleece-Full-Zip-Adult-Hoodie-style-F280-/141195688488

Comment: That's because 141195688488 is a Multi-Variation listing, so you would need to add Variations to the IncludeSelector. So in your case 'IncludeSelector':   'TextDescription, ItemSpecifics, Details, Variations'.